# Moving each value of a text file to its own line in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

This is a fairly simple question but I would like to know how to put each section of [this](http://pastebin.com/YMNZunWJ)
text file into it's own line, for example like this:

```
0.00000159
volume
645453536.89920200
lasttradetime
```

Thanks!

Comment: `printf '%s\n' $(wget -O- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YMNZunWJ)`. You didn't ask for shell, but some things are too simple even for Python. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lines = open("textfile").read().split()
```

That will split the whole file in parts using blanks (spaces, tabs, etc) as the separator. If you want to save it again to a file, each one on a line:

```
open("newtextfile", "w").write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your file makes me think that you want the last trade times to be kept together, e.g.

```
0.00000159
volume
645453536.89920200
lasttradetime
2014 03 06 10 32 03
```

So I'd recommend something like

```
import re
with open("infile.txt") as fp_in, open("outfile.txt", "w") as fp_out:
    d = fp_in.read()
    parts = re.split(r"\s\s+", d)
    for part in parts:
        fp_out.write(part + "\n")
```

which will achieve that.  (Probably be marginally faster to combine the parts and do one write, like `"\n".join(parts) + "\n"`.)

Answer (score 0):

To support arbitrary large files that might not fit in memory, you could use `mmap`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap

with open('filename', 'rb') as file:
    mm = mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ)
    try:
        with open('output', 'wb') as output_file:
            for m in re.finditer(r'\S+', mm):
                print >>output_file, m.group()
    finally:
        mm.close()
```